# How to speed up distcp when transferring data from Hadoop to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc, google-hadoop

The google cloud provides connectors for working with Hadoop.(https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/google-cloud-storage-connector)

Using the connector, I receive data from hdfs to google cloud storage

ex)

```
hadoop discp hdfs://${path} gs://${path}
```

but data is too large(16TB) and receive speed is just 2mb/s

So, I try to change set up distcp ( map property, bandwith property ... )

However speed is same.

How to speed up distcp when transferring data from HDFS to Google Cloud Storage

Comment: do you know if google has any parameters like amazon `fs.s3a.fast.upload=true`

Comment: google cloud does not have parameters like amazon.

Comment: Generally to achieve maximum throughput you need to set number of mappers to a number of files that you copy: `hadoop discp -m <NUMBER_OF_FILES> hdfs://${path} gs://${path}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migration/hadoop/hadoop-gcp-migration-data#improving_data_migration_speed) states that the one of the best options of transferring data from on-premises clusters to GCP is using a [VPN tunnel](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview) over the internet  or even using multiple [VPN tunnels](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/building-high-throughput-vpns) for additional bandwidth.

Other options proposed are using direct peering between Google's edge points of presence ([PoPs](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/locations)) and your network, or establishing a direct connection to Google's network with the help of a [Cloud Interconnect service provider](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/docs/concepts/service-providers).